# A property of the Anderson dual of the sphere spectrum

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy

Let $X$ be a spectrum, and let $I_{\mathbb{Z}}$ be the Anderson dual of the sphere. Using the definition of $I_{\mathbb{Z}}$, it is easy to get short exact sequences $$0\rightarrow Ext(\pi_{n-1}X, \mathbb{Z})\rightarrow I^n_{\mathbb{Z}}(X)\rightarrow Hom(\pi_nX,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow 0,$$ where $I^n_{\mathbb{Z}}(X)=\pi_{-n}F(X,I_{\mathbb{Z}})$. I have read that these short exact sequences split, but I cannot figure out how to get a splitting.

Comment: I don't know if these exact sequences split in general, but they do at least if the homotopy groups of X are degreewise finitely generated.

Comment: To complement skd's excellent comment in case it was not clear, the sequence split if $\pi_nX$ is finitely generated because the last term is a projective module (so nothing to do with topology, just algebra).